# Unable to see any message in website using flask

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-notebook

In my local host, I'm unable to see any message. I am using jupyter notebook.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")

def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.debug = True
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5005)
```

Comment: How did you access your website? What appears on the page when you access from localhost?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657127/display-flask-app-output-in-jupyter-notebook) may help you.